# Why are my Orcs so Big and Strong?

Tags: biology, fantasy-races, genetic-engineering

Here are the usual "Since warcraft 3" Orcs.

Men are between 2.0 and 2.7 meters tall.
In women from 1.7 meters to 2.5 meters.

Almost no fat.

Much stronger than humans "One orc is as strong as 100 human men! And that's normal, there are much stronger orcs."

Good regeneration. "A severed arm or leg grows back in a month."

Extremely strong body. "Dense skin and muscle makes them impossible to penetrate by spears and crossbow arrows! Firearms are very bad."

Quick for their weight.

Weight, from 130 kg in the smallest male orcs, to 380 in the largest and strongest.

Tendons are much stronger and stronger than in humans. Bones are gray because of the huge amount of carbon and micro carbon nano-tubes that they have been growing since Birth.

Reaction speed is much faster than a human. They're just as intelligent as humans. Many are smarter than we are.

Now here's the problem. How do we make them resilient?

My idea is this. Their green skin is capable of photosynthesis and the heat from their bodies throughout the day makes it almost impossible for them to get tired, "But they still need to eat." And I've come up with some kind of "Correct me if I'm wrong" micro organisms in their bodies that trap germs and other debris from the air and process it into food and energy and feed the orcs and their bodies that way.
Is this nonsense?

Is there a problem with all this? Is it possible to make such orcs more resilient than humans? Are my ideas realistic or delusional?
Help solve the stamina problem!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You will get better feedback if you break down your queries into one question per post.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is "the stamina problem"? Your orcs already sound a lot more resilient than humans, given all the magic strength and magic regeneration powers that they have.

Comment: Greetings Seeker of Knowledge! If you're asking about Warcraft, the best forum to ask this question would be the Sci-Fi and Fantasy forum. Also, it's best practice to wait a couple days before awarding the green check mark. Gives people a chance to even see your question!

Comment: with no body fat they will have the endurance of a toddler. About an hour of exercise completely depletes the glycogen reserves of a human. making them bigger makes the problem worse.  that could explain why humans always win in the long run, humans have amazing endurance they can just outlast orcs.

Comment: It's not regular fantasy. It's stealth science fiction "techno-fantasy" and I don't want magical orcs. I want scientifically biological orcs. If photosynthesis and micro-chemistry can't fully enable them to endure humans, what exactly should be done to make them more enduring? Tell me please.

Comment: First you accept an answer, then edit the question to make than answer invalid. Please, don't do it. Once you get answers, edits cannot invalidate them. If those answers make the edit impossible, blame the answerers for not following the "answer only well asked question" rule.

Comment: I say it again: no edits invalidating existing answers.

Comment: My suggestion would be to ask a new question, and cut it down to the meat of what it sounds like you want, which is what biological factors could be applied to make an earth-like humanoid species high endurance. Possibly that question would be closed for "brainstorming" but really it's a type of question we handle regularly and should be acceptable if it's focused. ("Brainstorming" is not a close reason. "Needs more focus" is the actual reason, so keep your question focused, and remember anyone without a diamond beside their name is just another user like you. Don't be intimidated!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your orcs have superpowers far beyond any real living creature. I judge them

$$ \large \text{    Unrealistic.}$$

Photosynthesis is not magic. It is not enough to power your musclebound superstuds. Have you seen plants? They barely move. That's the level of energy you get from photosynthesis.

Same with the microorganisms. Put some yeast in a cup with some flour and water. After a while it heats up and starts bubbling. That's the level of energy output you can expect from microorganisms.

Since your world already has gods, I suggest you stop worrying about realism. Just make sure to give these orcs consistent superpowers and you are good.

Comment: And secondly, why the anti-scientific skills?
Strength from the tendon, which in its structure and tension is similar to the silk of the spider, which is why there is such a force. Plus the muscles are like biological carbon nanotubes and the bones are gray. That's why they have such monstrous strength.
And cells with muscles are very dense and collected in biological framework as the same decanter. That is why their body is essentially biological and very strong chitin and it is only skin, muscles and meat under the skin are the same dense if not better. So where is the anti-scientific?

Comment: What is "anti-scientific skills"?

Comment: you can also add skin that can withstand spears, the skin of elephants, crocodiles and turtles cannot reliably withstand spears.

Comment: I meant "Why Antiscientific? "

Comment: What is "antiscientific"?

Comment: Did you try and eave a first comment before the one that starts with "And secondly. . . "?

Comment: [Relevant XKCD](https://what-if.xkcd.com/17/) for the first part. Even a grazing animal such as a cow could only derive a few percent of its energy needs from photosynthesis... and cows aren't exactly known for their physical fitness.

Comment: @Cadence The give away is how the grassy fields they keep cows in are much bigger than the cow itself.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your orcs are not using Earthly biology. Creatures with metabolisms which perform *that* well must be artificial, carefully designed, and probably have hidden limitations. Let's see if we can discover some of them?

The thing that definitely can't work is powering their bodies by photosynthesis. They simply don't have enough surface area to collect enough light to power them. If they were designed for an environment with a *much* brighter sun, either because it's very close to their usual habitat, or it's much larger and/or hotter than our sun, it might be practical. That fits with them being designed, rather than evolved. However, they'll find the light on any earth like planet very dim, the temperature very low, and they'll need to eat a lot more than at home.

Can that approach work for you?

Comment: According to history, they were created by a god as the strongest beings of this world. But this is techno-fantasy, so they don't work magic, but biology.

What I meant about photosynthesis is that it is supplementary, not the main way of feeding. The main one is food and microorganisms in the skin and body that take and process micro bacteria into energy and food for orcs.

Again, is this biology or is this nonsense?

Comment: Nonsense, I'm afraid. Just not enough material to supply the needed energy via chemistry.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker Have you seen plants? They barely move. That's the level of energy you get from photosynthesis.

Comment: I suggested photosynthesis. What about microorganisms?
In general, how can you make orcs of the question more hardy than humans?

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker You will not get any more believable superpowers using microorganisms. People and animals are already made of micro-organisms. Micro-organisms that joined together and learnt how to much much faster and in more complicated ways than a puddle of goop.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker: You have `science-based` as a tag on your question. This constrains answers considerably. For a few examples, just about all fictional super-powers, all "magic" and a great deal of "science fiction" are excluded by that tag. If you're trying to come up with something like Star Wars' "midichlorians" they're about as science-based as the Easter Bunny.